# "Add a VPN connection" is greyed out

Tags: networking, 16.04, vpn, openvpn

I installed openvpn on my Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS System, but I can't add a connection, because the field is greyed out.

I've tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

Is there maybe any super secret file I have to edit?

Edit:
Also tried to solve it via installing the following packages:

```
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-vpnc
```

Edit 2:
The suggested solution in the comment from alfred worked for me:

> I'm on 16.04.2, but I don't see "Add a VPN connection" option on nm-applet. > However I can add a VPN connection by choosing "Edit conections..." -> "Add" > – alfred Mar 17 at 23:55

Comment: The solution there did not work for me. Added it in my post via edit

Comment: I'm on 16.04.2, but I don't see "Add a VPN connection" option on nm-applet. However I can add a VPN connection by choosing "Edit conections..." -> "Add"